# Javascript a new line in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like so:

```
var customerInfo = data[0].Customer_Name + " " + data[0].Customer_LName + "\r\n" + data[0].Phone + "\r\n" + data[0].Email;
```

and I am trying to add new lines with \r\n but its not working, everything is on the same line. Please Help.

Comment: Downvoted: please provide a reproducible demo. Remember that in HTML, `<br>` stays for newline, not `\n`.

Comment: "Everything is one on the same line". where exactly? Where are you outputing the string to?

Comment: HTML uses `<br />` for line breaks, since it's a markup language, so, `\n` isn't really a new line unless you're in a `<pre>` block.

Comment: "\r\n" may separate lines in the source code, but remember that HTML doesn't care about whitespace. To create a new line in the rendered HTML use "<br/>"

Answer (score 1):

To print the javascript variable in an HTML page, you should use the `<br />` tag to create a new line, instead `\r\n`.

```
var customerInfo = data[0].Customer_Name + " " + data[0].Customer_LName + "<br />" + data[0].Phone + "<br />" + data[0].Email;
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer unclear questions. As it stays now, it's just a guess.